# Will a Canon dSLR retain settings if the battery is removed for an extended period of time?

Tags: canon, battery, canon-50d

If I remove the rechargeable BP battery from my Canon EOS 50D for an extended period of time, will the internal lithium battery preserve all of my settings (including custom functions, date/time, etc.)?

Comment: You'd should qualify 'extended'. Months, no problem. Years, will be because the internal rechargeable battery eventually runs out (even if on some high-end models it is replaceable).

Comment: We're talking like 5+ years.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes.

All modern canon dslr's have a small lithium battery (similar to the one that is used to power your computers CMOS) that powers the internal memory that retains the settings.